# Django Changes Type of Variable on Override Save Function Call

Tags: python, django

Django seems to be changing the type of my variable after calling the resizeUploadedImage method from type str to type Project while overriding the save method.

I previously had this method working properly, but then I moved the logic outside of the save method and into another one that is called inside of save. I did this so I could do multiple things before saving but it seems now when I call the resizeUploadedImage method the variable I pass is being changed from a str to a Project. 
I tried adding a str(fname) to the variable call.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.image:
        url = self.image.url
        surl = url.split('/')
        fname = surl[-1]

        print('\t TRYING TO RESIZE IMAGE')
        print('filename',fname)
        print('top type', type(fname))
        self.resizeUploadedImage(self, fname)

        # the additional function I wanted to add
        # self.createThumbnail(self, fname)
      super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
def resizeUploadedImage(self, fname, *args):
    '''Resize the image being uploaded.'''
    print('resize top type', type(fname))
    try:
        im = Image.open(self.image)
        print(im.size)
        if im.size > IMAGE_SIZE:
            im_sized = im.resize(IMAGE_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image_io = BytesIO()
            im_sized.save(image_io, im.format)
            print('resize type', type(fname))
            self.image.save(fname, ContentFile(image_io.getvalue(), False))
    except IOError as e:
        print("Could not resize image for", self.image)
        print(e)
```

When I run this inside the Django shell, it works properly and resizes the image however when I run my tests I get 
    TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'Project'

Edit: I kind of have 2 questions here. 
1: How can I make sure the variable stays as the intended str? 
2: I chose to pass the variable rather than manually grabbing the name as I did originally in each method to avoid duplicate code. Is that the proper mentality, or should I just grab it to ensure integrity?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.resizeUploadedImage(self, fname)
```

This is not correct. You have duplicated self.

Comment: So what does that mean I should do? Should I instead do something like 
    self.resizeUploadedImage(self.image, fname)

    def resizeUploadedImage(image, fname):

Comment: Dont' call with self as first argument. You need to understand Python a little bit more. Just self.resizeUploadedImage(fname) will do. Why are you having *args? That is hiding the error.

Comment: With 
    self.resizeUploadedImage(fname)
    def resizeUploadedImage(self, fname):
I get UNIQUE constraint failed: projects_project.id
When I take self out of the def I get 1 positional argument but 2 were given. I've been self-teaching myself Python, so apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: The UNIQUE constraint error is from when you save the project. So the resize operation worked. Use the pdb debugger to see what happens exactly.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your help thus far. 
I was able to resolve the unique constraint error by moving my super.save call to the top of my function rather than at the end. 
It seems I am still having a recursion issue though. Django seems to be saving images multiple times while splitting up my filename. I am getting files like '1_cover.PNG' and '1project 1_cover.PNG' and 'project_cover.PNG' when I am expecting 'Project 1_cover.PNG'
I am starting to think I should open a new question as its hard to share information in these comments.

Comment: Testing with the admin I am able to create a project and it resized and names the image correctly.. so my error is only in the test DB. I am not sure why my test db is saving to my disk in the first place